# 90 minutes enough for domestic to International transfer at LAX?

Tags: airports, layovers, airport-security, lax

Traveling from Austin, TX to Beijing with a connection in LAX. Both legs book at the same time through AA official website. The first flight arrives at Terminal 4 and the second leg leaves from Tom Bradly International Terminal in 1 hr and 30 minutes.

There are varied opinions about whether this transfer is doable or not all over the internet. Doing some research did not help solve all my concerns:

1. can checked baggage go from Austin to Beijing without being rechecked in LAX? Do I have to go through security again in LAX?
2. on the official website of LAX, the map shows me a tunnel that connects T4 to Tom Bradley, which would be super convenient. How long would it take for me to get through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no procedural difference between a departing domestic flight and a departing international flight in the US, so your question would be the same as one for a domestic-to-domestic transfer.

Generally, checked luggage is checked through from one flight to another when you have booked it on the same ticket with the same airline, so you shouldn't have to claim your baggage.

There is an above-ground (not tunnel) post-security connector between TBIT and Terminal 4 at LAX, so you shouldn't have to go through security again. It should only take a few minutes to walk between the terminals.